# Share data between viewmodels

Tags: android

I have an activity containing an associated view model. The view model loads the data from an online repository. In the same activity I have a table layout containing a viewpager. In the view page are several fragments.

How can I access the activity view model in my fragments?

Answer (score -1):

you can share viewmodel between fragments like this

class MasterFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var itemSelector: Selector

private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    model = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
    itemSelector.setOnClickListener { item ->
        // Update the UI
    }
}
```

}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    model = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
    model.selected.observe(this, Observer<Item> { item ->
        // Update the UI
    })
}
```

}

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

or just make your viewmodel in your activity public then call it in your fragment like:

(activity as MainActivity).viewmodel // MainActivity is your activity